# How to interate through array in groupped object by key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the given array I'm groupping by property called `Value` and the result is an object where key is the `Value` and value are matching `arrays`.
Now I'm trying to loop and output all the `data` by `key`.
So desired output would be to display all objects by it's key.
Smth like in the screenshot below, only in my case data is groupped by Value.

[image]

Here is the code and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-hooks-19zkbb?file=/src/App.js:0-925)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { groupBy } from "lodash";

const data = [
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" }
];
export default function App() {
  const grouppedByValue = groupBy(data, "Value");
  console.log(grouppedByValue);
  console.log(Object.keys(grouppedByValue));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Object.entries` for that in this way

```
import "./styles.css";
import { groupBy } from "lodash";

const data = [
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" }
];
export default function App() {
  const grouppedByValue = groupBy(data, "Value");
  console.log(grouppedByValue);
  console.log(Object.keys(grouppedByValue));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {Object.entries(grouppedByValue).map(([value, items]) => <div key={value}>
  <div>{value}</div>
   <ul>
     {items.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>Phase :{item.Phase} </li>)
   </ul>
</div>)
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you edit the post, I will assume that you're trying to map over each key of the `grouppedByValue` object, and then iterate the array of each `grouppedByValue[key]`.

This is an example:

```
      {Object.entries(grouppedByValue).map(([key, value], kidx) => (
        <div key={`k-${kidx}`}>
          {value.map((el, idx) => (
            <span key={`el-${idx}`}>{JSON.stringify(el)}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
```

Note that I'm using `kidx` and `idx` to give children the necessary keys as requested by React.

This example outputs the whole object, but feel free to extract the necessary information from it.

If you are not familiar with `Object.entries()`, check out this [documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

This is the full implementation based on your sample.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { groupBy } from "lodash";

const data = [
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" }
];
export default function App() {
  const grouppedByValue = groupBy(data, "Value");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {Object.entries(grouppedByValue).map(([key, value], kidx) => (
        <div key={`k-${kidx}`}>
          {value.map((el, idx) => (
            <span key={`el-${idx}`}>{JSON.stringify(el)}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Output image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` to get both key and value at same time.

DOM structure to make similar to OP's screenshot.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { groupBy } from "lodash";

const data = [
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
  { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" }
];
export default function App() {
  const grouppedByValue = groupBy(data, "Value");
  console.log(grouppedByValue);
  console.log(Object.keys(grouppedByValue));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {Object.entries(grouppedByValue).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div>
          <div><strong>{key}</strong></div>
          {value.map((el) => (
            <div>{el.Phase}, {el.Step}, {el.Task}</div>
          ))}
        </div> 
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]